# How to change local host to a 'domain name'

Tags: javascript, dns, localhost, cpanel

Instead of seeing localhost:4400/index.html, I have to show it as itproj19.projectsit.org/index.html . I am using cpanel for my database.

I tried putting in the html, css and js files into the public_html but it only show the html layout without reading the js and css.

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly, so do help if you know the method of how I can go about changing the localhost.

Comment: I think this is rather something for https://superuser.com/ than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you share the folder tree?

Comment: Do you control `projectsit.org`?

Comment: check the browser console for errors, I think you have a bad path to files, try to change path to relative './path/main.js' e g